# Use separation of variables with the given Cauchy data to solve a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

> Consider $\Delta u=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2,$ with the Cauchy data: 
>   $$u=0, \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2} = \frac{1}{n} \sin(n x_1),~~\textrm{on}~\{ X_2 = 0 \}.$$

My approach: WLOG let $X_1(x_1)=X(x)$ and $X_2(x_2)=Y(y).$ Now separation of variables, $u(x , y)=X(x) Y(y)$ yields:
$$\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-\frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}=-\lambda~~\textrm{for}~\lambda >0.$$
Now solving the two ODEs yield:
$$X(x)=A \cos \sqrt{\lambda}x + B \sin \sqrt{\lambda}x~~,~~Y(y)=C \cosh\sqrt{\lambda}y + B \sinh \sqrt{\lambda}y.$$

Can someone please explain me how to use the Cauchy data to complete the given problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I suppose this is a problem from Evans book, right? Since this is a typical homework problem in many courses using that book, I won't give more than a hint: do a little pattern matching between the expression for $u=XY$ you have now, and the Cauchy data. You might want to figure out what the constants $A,B,C,D,\lambda$ should / could be in order to satisfy them. Also, it is ok to let $\lambda$ be an expression depending on $n$.

Comment: @A.Sh, is this from Evans ? I don't know. And of course $\lambda$ depends on $n$ as it's the case for separation of variable problems. I just don't know how to use the Cauchy data to determine the constants and come up with a series representation.

Comment: I checked in Evans book, and this is identical to one part of exercise 2 in chapter 4 (the second part is arguing that the given Cauchy problem isn't well-posed by taking the limit as $n$ grows to infinity). I guess this is probably an exercise (or variation of) that occurs in many other places as well. Someone just posted an answer with a hint that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT :
$$u(x,y)=\left(A \cos \sqrt{\lambda}x + B \sin \sqrt{\lambda}x\right)\left(C \cosh\sqrt{\lambda}y + D \sinh \sqrt{\lambda}y\right).$$
$$\begin{cases} 
\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)_{y=0} =\left(A \cos \sqrt{\lambda}x + B \sin \sqrt{\lambda}x\right)D\sqrt{\lambda} 
=\frac{1}{n} \sin(n x) \quad\to\quad 
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{\lambda}=? \\
A=? \\
BD=?
\end{cases} \\
u(x,0)=\left(A \cos \sqrt{\lambda}x + B \sin \sqrt{\lambda}x\right)C=0 \quad\to\quad C=?
\end{cases}$$

Comment: thank you very much. So doesn't it have to be the series expansion for $u(x,y)$ to begin with ? The first equation yields, $A=0,~\sqrt{\lambda}=n,~~BD=1/{n^2}$  while the second yields $C=0.$

Comment: That should be an alternative method : guessing a function of the form $C(n)\sin(nx)f(y)$ and putting it into the PDE and condition should be a short way.

Comment: I see. Thanks again. :)